# i need an explanation about how this code insert the data to my table in my database (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

This is my code in my `CategoryController.php`

```
public function addCategory(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->all();
      //  echo "<pre>", print_r($data);die;
        $category = new Category;//in the http
        $category->name = $data['category_name'];
        $category->description = $data['description'];
        $category->url = $data['url'];
        $category->save();
    }
    else{

    }
    return view('admin.categories.add_category');
  }
}
```

my table name in databse is `categories`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: database connection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database

Laravel sets the connection automagically behind the scenes. Your config/database.php file contains database credentials and host (the actual values here are usually stored in a .env file in the root directory of the app). Laravel will boot, take those database.php configuration values and connect to the database

Step 2: Eloquent ORM

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Laravel incorporates Eloquent ORM for abstracting communication with database. Each table in the database can be bound to a class which in eloquent is called a Model. This is how the Category.php class file probably looks like:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    // This variable tells eloquent which table this model is trying to access.
    protected $table = 'categories';
}
```

Then in the CategoryController a new model is created.

```
// Create a new model instance - this is like creating a new row in an SQL editor.
$category = new Category;

// Here, you set the field values of the row.
// Each of the attributes below corresponds to a column name in the table.
// Right now this data is not in the database.
$category->name = $data['category_name'];
$category->description = $data['description'];
$category->url = $data['url'];

// And here we call the save() method, to actually execute the insert command.
// This is going to construct a query behind the scenes, and using the database
// connection set in configuration file, send it to the server and execute it.
$category->save();

// And here, a new row is already inserted in the database and you can access
// all of it's values.
var_dump($category->id);
```

I suggest you to read up on Laravel documentation - it's really well written and easy to understand, and a lot of these basics can be googled and there's a lot of information out there.

Comment: thanks sir. now i get it ,i really appreciate your help